# Three.js maze design gaps between wall?

Tags: javascript, three.js, maze

so I'm having trouble with fixing the gaps between the walls when creating a maze in three.js I was hoping someone could help to find a solution for it

P.S.: the H stand for horizontal and V for vertical in the maze design layout

Here is the code I'm using:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>3D Maze in Three.js</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { display: block; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module">
        import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.1/build/three.module.js';
        import { PointerLockControls } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.1/examples/jsm/controls/PointerLockControls.js';

        let camera, scene, renderer, controls;
        let moveForward = false;
        let moveLeft = false;
        let moveBackward = false;
        let moveRight = false;
        let prevTime = performance.now();
        const velocity = new THREE.Vector3();
        const direction = new THREE.Vector3();

        function init() {
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x87CEEB); // Blue sky

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
            camera.position.set(0, 50, 0);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            controls = new PointerLockControls(camera, document.body);
            scene.add(controls.getObject());

            document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
                controls.lock();
            }, false);

            document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
            document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);

            createMaze();
        }

        function createMaze() {
    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const wallGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(4, 4, 1); // Wall dimensions

    const wallMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        map: textureLoader.load('Brick/Brick_Color.jpg'),
        aoMap: textureLoader.load('Brick/Brick_Ambient occlusion.jpg'),
        normalMap: textureLoader.load('Brick/Brick_Normal.jpg'),
        roughnessMap: textureLoader.load('Brick/Brick_Roughness.jpg')
    });

    // ... Texture wrapping settings ...

    // Explicit maze layout with orientations
    const mazeLayout = [
    "HVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVH",
    "H     H     H       H",
    "H VVV V VVV V VVVVV H",
    "H H   H   H H H   H H",
    "H H VVVVV H H H H H H",
    "H H     H H   H H   H",
    "H VVVVV H VVVVV VVVVH",
    "H     H H     H     H",
    "VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV"
    ];


    const floorSize = 200;
    const wallSpacing = 4; // Adjust if needed

    // Create walls based on the maze layout
mazeLayout.forEach((row, i) => {
    row.split('').forEach((cell, j) => {
        if (cell === 'H' || cell === 'V') {
            const wall = new THREE.Mesh(wallGeometry, wallMaterial);
            const isHorizontal = cell === 'H';

            // Position without offset
            const xPosition = (j - mazeLayout[0].length / 2) * wallSpacing;
            const zPosition = (i - mazeLayout.length / 2) * wallSpacing;

            wall.position.set(xPosition, 2, zPosition);

            // Rotate wall if it's horizontal
            if (isHorizontal) {
                wall.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2;
                // Since the wall is rotated, the x and z positions need to be swapped
                wall.position.x += wallSpacing / 2;
                wall.position.z += wallSpacing / 2;
            } else {
                // No rotation needed for vertical walls, but we still adjust the z position
                wall.position.z += wallSpacing / 2;
            }

            scene.add(wall);
        }
    });
});



    // Floor creation
    const floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        map: textureLoader.load('Cement/Cement_Color.jpg'),
        //displacementMap: textureLoader.load('Cement/Cement_Displacement.jpg'),
        normalMap: textureLoader.load('Cement/Cement_Normal.jpg'),
        roughnessMap: textureLoader.load('Cement/Cement_Roughness.jpg')
    });

    floorMaterial.map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    floorMaterial.map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    floorMaterial.map.repeat.set(50, 50); // Adjust for texture size

    //floorMaterial.displacementMap.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    //floorMaterial.displacementMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    //floorMaterial.displacementMap.repeat.set(50, 50);

    floorMaterial.normalMap.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    floorMaterial.normalMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    floorMaterial.normalMap.repeat.set(50, 50);

    floorMaterial.roughnessMap.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    floorMaterial.roughnessMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    floorMaterial.roughnessMap.repeat.set(50, 50);

    const floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(floorSize, floorSize);
    const floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
    floor.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
    floor.position.y = -0.5; // Slightly lower to prevent z-fighting with the walls
    scene.add(floor);

        // Add lighting (omitted for brevity)

    // Ambient light to softly light the scene
    const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    // Directional light to simulate sunlight
    const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    directionalLight.position.set(50, 50, 50);
    scene.add(directionalLight);
}


        function onKeyDown(event) {
            switch (event.code) {
                case 'ArrowUp':
                case 'KeyW':
                    moveForward = true;
                    break;
                case 'ArrowLeft':
                case 'KeyA':
                    moveLeft = true;
                    break;
                case 'ArrowDown':
                case 'KeyS':
                    moveBackward = true;
                    break;
                case 'ArrowRight':
                case 'KeyD':
                    moveRight = true;
                    break;
            }
        }

        function onKeyUp(event) {
            switch (event.code) {
                case 'ArrowUp':
                case 'KeyW':
                    moveForward = false;
                    break;
                case 'ArrowLeft':
                case 'KeyA':
                    moveLeft = false;
                    break;
                case 'ArrowDown':
                case 'KeyS':
                    moveBackward = false;
                    break;
                case 'ArrowRight':
                case 'KeyD':
                    moveRight = false;
                    break;
            }
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            const time = performance.now();
            const delta = (time - prevTime) / 1000;

            velocity.x -= velocity.x * 10.0 * delta;
            velocity.z -= velocity.z * 10.0 * delta;

            direction.z = Number(moveForward) - Number(moveBackward);
            direction.x = Number(moveRight) - Number(moveLeft);
            direction.normalize(); // this ensures consistent movements in all directions

            if (moveForward || moveBackward) velocity.z -= direction.z * 400.0 * delta;
            if (moveLeft || moveRight) velocity.x -= direction.x * 400.0 * delta;

            controls.moveRight(-velocity.x * delta);
            controls.moveForward(-velocity.z * delta);

            prevTime = time;

            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        init();
        animate();
    </script>
</body>
</html>"
```

type here

I tried a lot of things none worked like putting rules when the walls need to be rotated

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Like the bot said, reduce your problem. Remove textures and other maps. Assign basic color materials so you can see what's happening. Try placing just two blocks together by hard-coding their transformation values. Share screenshots of what it looks like for you, so others can compare their observations.